# How to set a NSString in a class from a uitextfield from a viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I am tying to set NSString *receiveCodeText; thats in an object with a uitextfiled value thats in my viewcontroller from my viewcontroller inside tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: however I am getting an error

> /Users/imac/Documents/Iphone
>   applications/tables/Classes/RootViewController.m:198:0 /Users/imac/Documents/Iphone
>   applications/tables/Classes/RootViewController.m:198:
>   error: accessing unknown
>   'setReceiveCodeText:' class method
>
> /Users/imac/Documents/Iphone
>   applications/tables/Classes/RootViewController.m:198:0 /Users/imac/Documents/Iphone
>   applications/tables/Classes/RootViewController.m:198:
>   error: object cannot be set - either
>   readonly property or no setter found

here is my code and how I am trying to pass the text.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    searchTableViewController *searchTable = [[searchTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"searchTableViewController" bundle:nil];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 1: {
            searchTable.editedFieldName = @"Make";
            //Pass code number over to DBAccess class
            DBAccess.receiveCodeText = self.codeText.text;
        } break;
        case 2: {
            searchTable.editedFieldName = @"Model";
        } break;
        case 3: {
            searchTable.editedFieldName = @"Year";
        } break;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchTable animated:YES];
    [searchTable release];
}
```

Comment: you can't set properties on classes, your using property shorthand to set a value on `DBAccess` (which i assume is your class?) class (NOT an instance of the class), i'm surprised this even compiled, are there compiler warnings?  anyway, i think you want to get hold of an instance of the class.

Comment: Did you @synthesize it ?

Comment: bshirley this didnt compile :) I have it all working when I hardcode my sqlquery but I am wanting to set it at run time hence this code :)

Comment: I see what your saying though, and now realise how stupid it was that I was trying to send a value to my class not the instance to my class... The only thing now Is I am not sure when I can pass this variable across to my class instance..

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean by defined?

Comment: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//include header for sqlite
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "instaCodeDB.h"


@interface DBAccess : NSObject {
 
 NSString *receiveCodeText;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *receiveCodeText;

- (NSMutableArray *) getAllMakes;
- (void) closeDatabase;
- (void) initalizeDatabase;

@end
`

Answer (score 0):

`DBAccess` is a class. Unless `setRecieveCodeText:` is a class method, you can't use it directly. Properties belong to the instance rather than the class so you will have to declare class methods and use a static variable to handle this. However it makes sense to instantiate and then use that object or even using a singleton if you want to avoid multiple instances of the same class. A singleton should be available for use across classes.

I've included code related to the class method approach.

```
@interface DBAccess: NSObject {
}

+ (NSString *)receiveCodeText;
+ (void)setReceiveCodeText:(NSString *)code;
[..]
@end
```

In the `.m` file,

```
static NSString * receiveCodeText;

@implementation DBAccess
[..]
+ (NSString *)receiveCodeText {
    return receiveCodeText;
}

+ (void)setReceiveCodeText:(NSString *)code {
    [receiveCodeText autorelease];
    receiveCodeText = [code copy];
}
[..]
@end
```